# How do I make an array of objects conform to my protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

I'm trying to create a nice generic wrapper for fetching and handling data. The purpose would be that a model can implement the protocol and therefore be compatible with my generic wrapper, but I'm having a few issues in doing this.

I've noticed that the `Codable` protocol acts the way that I want my protocol to act, it seems like an array of objects that inherit `Codable` are treated as a conforming data type. This doesn't seem to be the case for the protocol I've created however.

Here's the jist of what I'm trying to achieve:

```swift
protocol MyProtocol {
  static var name: String { get }
}
```

```swift
class MyService<T: MyProtocol> {

  let otherService = MyOtherService<T>()
}
```

```swift
struct MyModel: MyProtocol {
  let id: Int
  let name: String

  static var name: String {
    return "Name"
  }
```

And instantiation:

```swift
let service = MyService<[MyModel]>()
```

but I'm being met with the error `Type '[MyModel]' does not conform to protocol 'MyProtocol'`

I know that it's possible because `Codable` acts the way that I would want to use my protocol, but I'm unsure of how to achieve this and whether it carries more work than is warranted for the outcome. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The feature you described is called conditional conformance, i.e. if X is Equatable then an array of X is also Equatable. It requires works in the standard library so it is not available for every protocol out there. See https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The generic type

Look at the generic type you are using here

```
let service = MyService<[MyModel]>()
```

The generic type is NOT `MyModel` but `[MyModel]`.

In other words an `Array of MyModel` which does not conform to `MyProtocol`.

### The fix

You can fix it conforming an `Array of MyModel` to `MyProtocol`

```
extension Array: MyProtocol where Element == MyModel {
    static var name: String {
        return "Array of MyModel"
    }
}
```

### Test

Now you can write

```
let service = MyService<[MyModel]>()
```

---

## UPDATE

I was thinking we can go a little bit further here.

Instead of creating an extension for an `Array of MyModel` we could create an extension for any Array where the generic type conforms to `MyProtocol`.

```
extension Array: MyProtocol where Element : MyProtocol {
    static var name: String {
        return Element.name
    }
}
```

Now if you define a new type conforming (`MyNewModel`) to MyProtocol, automatically an array of `MyNewModel` will automatically conform to `MyProtocol`. Just like it happens for `Equatable` and `Codable`.